# Why am I getting a blank plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The objective is to compare the data to the same ‘Customer No’ that matches the most recent information from the user’s input. I am getting a blank plot.

Given that I have the data presented in this way:

```
Customer No | Customer Type | Order Time |  Order Amount |Order Quantity
120023 | Non Regular| 25/1/2023 00:00:00 |  470.92 |    13
120023 | Regular         |25/1/2023 00:00:00  | 64.03   |             7
120024 |Non Regular  |  25/1/2023 00:00:00 |    143.18  |   3
120024  |Regular           |25/1/2023 00:00:00 |    143.18  |            3
120025  |Non Regular   |25/1/2023 00:00:00 |    222.14  |            1
120025  |Regular            |25/1/2023 00:00:00 |   222.14  |   1
120006  |Non Regular    |25/1/2023 00:00:00 |   157.18  |            5
120007  |Non Regular    |25/1/2023 00:00:00 |   151.51  |   7
120008  |Non Regular    |25/1/2023 00:00:00 |   99.7    |            7 
119990  |Non Regular    |25/1/2023 00:00:00 |   212.48  |            1
119991  |Non Regular    |25/1/2023 00:00:00 |   96.53   |            3
119992  |Non Regular    |25/1/2023 00:00:00 |   62.72   |            7
119993 |Non Regular |25/1/2023 00:00:00 |   87.89    |            7
119994  |Non Regular    |25/1/2023 00:00:00  | 96.56    |            1
119995 |Non Regular |25/1/2023 00:00:00 | 95.44 |           1
119996  |Non Regular    |25/1/2023 00:00:00 | 97.03 |           3
```

I created a code to look at the data I have collected. The objective is to compare the data to the same ‘Customer No’ that matches the most recent information from the user’s input. You can also see that for each of the next 2 rows, it has the same ‘Customer No’ parameter, but the customer type is between Non-Regular and Regular, and the task is to take the row with the lowest order amount and order quantity, and the data points will be plotted together.

From here, I want to plot the Customer No’s data separately with the y-axis being the ‘Order Quantity’ variable and the x-axis is the ‘Order Time’ variable. Why did it return an empty plot? How do I fix this?

The full code :

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('FoodOrder.xlsx')

input_date = input("Enter a date (format: yyyy/mm/dd): ")
input_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y/%m/%d")

df['Order Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Time'])

df['time_diff'] = (df['Order Time'] - input_date).dt.days

df_filtered = df[(df['time_diff'] >= -20) & (df['time_diff'] <= 20)]


df_grouped = df_filtered.groupby('Customer No').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Order Amount'].idxmax()] if x['Order Amount '].max() > x['Order Quantity'].max() else x.loc[x['Order Quantity'].idxmax()])


# Reset the index of the grouped dataframe
df_grouped = df_grouped.reset_index(drop=True)


# Define a plotting function
def plot_customer(x):
    plt.plot(x['Order Time'], x['Order Amount'])
    plt.xlabel('Order Time')
    plt.ylabel('Order Amount')
    plt.title('Order Amount vs Order Time for Customer No: ' + str(x['Customer No'].iloc[0]))
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.ylim(0, x['Order Amount'].max() * 1.1)
    plt.show()

    plt.show()

# Apply the plotting function to each group
df_grouped.groupby('Customer No').apply(plot_customer)
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. It should be 'Order Time' . Even when the variables are called accurately, it still returned a blank plot. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining the `marker`:

```
plt.plot(x['Order Time'], x['Order Amount'], marker = 'o')
```

If you want to make a plot for each Customer Num, this can be done by this code:

```
nums = df['Customer No'].unique()
for num in nums:
    x = df[df['Customer No'] == num]
    plot_customer(x)
```

Your full above code should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('FoodOrder.xlsx')

input_date = input("Enter a date (format: yyyy/mm/dd): ")
input_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y/%m/%d")

df['Order Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Time'])

df['time_diff'] = (df['Order Time'] - input_date).dt.days

df_filtered = df[(df['time_diff'] >= -20) & (df['time_diff'] <= 20)]


df_grouped = df_filtered.groupby('Customer No').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Order Amount'].idxmax()] if x['Order Amount '].max() > x['Order Quantity'].max() else x.loc[x['Order Quantity'].idxmax()])


# Reset the index of the grouped dataframe
df_grouped = df_grouped.reset_index(drop=True)


# Define a plotting function
def plot_customer(x):
    plt.plot(x['Order Time'], x['Order Amount'])
    plt.xlabel('Order Time')
    plt.ylabel('Order Amount')
    plt.title('Order Amount vs Order Time for Customer No: ' + str(x['Customer No'].iloc[0]))
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.ylim(0, x['Order Amount'].max() * 1.1)
    plt.show()

    plt.show()

# Apply the plotting function to each group
nums = df['Customer No'].unique()
for num in nums:
    x = df[df['Customer No'] == num]
    plot_customer(x)
```

Comment: It appeared as a dot.

Comment: And this is what you wanted?

Comment: Not really. There are other ['Order Amount'] data points associated with the same ‘Customer No’ parameter that I hope to include. It's not reflected on the plot.

Comment: I appreciate your sincere and fast reply. Apparently, it returned this output: https://imgur.com/a/XuEatLH

Comment: Well...I don't have your full dataset but my code should result in a plot per customer. I have also added the updated full code above